# plugins in cordova 2.2.0 not working

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I upgraded to Cordova 2.2.0 and found out that my Plugins doesn't work!

It does not load but it compiles properly. I can't seem to get my Plugins to work. Any ideas?

I was using 1.9.0 before then tried to update also what I did is created the project then stored my code on the project folder.

Comment: You're not even saying which platform. And did you follow the [Upgrade Guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_upgrading_index.md.html#Upgrading%20Guides)?

Answer (score 0):

I have almost the same issue.
I make breakpoints in CDVBarcodeScanner.mm but no result, I just do not have any enter to this file.
Tried even variants like replacing Cordova with cordova, changing key in Cordova.plist from 'org.apache.cordova.barcodeScanner' to 'CDVBarcodeScanner' and in barcodescanner.js file did corresponding changes as well but ungortunately nothing helped me.
As man used github source. Have Cordova 2.2.0 installed and iOS.

Comment: Well, for now everything is ok. I tried one more time from the very beginning. May be due to freshly updated files of this plugin, but it works, enters into CDVBarcodeScanner.mm file so I don't have any trouble with it.

Comment: I think my problem was in using not the last version  of plugin. Some files were updated 9 days ago, so may be You have the same?